# Running PHPUnit test in PhpStorm adds "--teamcity" option causing error

Tags: phpunit, teamcity, phpstorm

I have the latest PhpStorm (2016.2) and PHPUnit phar (5.5.4). For some reason when I run a PHPUnit test in my project in PhpStorm, it is adding on `--teamcity` to the run command, resulting in a failure:

```
Testing started at 12:52 PM ...
Unit test suite invoked with a path to a non-unit test: --teamcity
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no idea where this `--teamcity` option is coming from, it happens no matter what test I run, and even when starting from a blank configuration. I also do NOT have the TeamCity plugin installed, I don't even use TeamCity.

Here's what the full command appears as:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.9/bin/php /Users/name/bin/phpunit-5.5.4.phar --configuration /path/to/config/my-phpunit.xml ClassNameTest /Users/name/PhpstormProjects/path/to/tests/unit/app/ClassNameTest.php --teamcity
```

(sensitive information swapped out)

All I want to do is get rid of this `--teamcity` option, everything works if I run in a separate terminal window without that option. This only recently started happening, maybe after a PhpStorm update.

Comment: I believe `--teamcity` here is a name of the Results Printer (or whatever it's properly called) so that IDE can monitor and follow tests execution in real time (update GUI with results and current progress). Such printer just prints test execution info in a format that IDE understands, that's it. This parameter does not hurt my PHPUnit test execution (PhpStorm 2016.2.1; PHPUnit 5.5.4 & 5.0.8; PHP 5.6.25 & 7.0.10; Windows 7).

Comment: This is full command: `E:\Projects\php70\php.exe E:\Projects\web\_libs\lib3\vendor\phpunit-5.5.4.phar --configuration E:\Projects\web\_libs\lib3\tests\phpunit-ide.xml Core\Tests\Helpers\InputTest E:\Projects\web\_libs\lib3\tests\Core\Helpers\InputTest.php --teamcity`

Comment: @LazyOne interesting. Even when I switch to the console, I get the same error. Tried in both `fish` and `bash` shells. When I move the `--teamcity` option to before `--configuration`, it works and outputs in teamcity format. What would cause the script to recognize `--teamcity` as a unit test and not an option argument?

Comment: Out of curiosity: 1) Try in brand new project with basic (but yet real) test case 2) Try backing up and deleting your IDE-wide config (to start from fresh) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs -- this is to check if it has anything to do with IDE settings. But so far it does not look like IDE related issue (at least it's my impression so far). If you did PhpStorm update via built-in update -- try downloading full installation package instead.

Comment: Yep. OK so it's some kind of dependency problem or bug. I check the paratest open source project and the `--teamcity` option is there but everything works. Something about the command runner or reader is not able to interpret that `--teamcity` option in my other project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was internal to the project. PHPUnit does not contain that error message. Sorry!

Comment: If your project is not super-private -- consider providing some reproducible sample project to the JetBrains' Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI (attachments can be made visible to JB members only) -- maybe they can suggest some workaround .. or maybe they will provide some option in the future that will place such `--teamcity` parameter earlier (before other params)

Comment: @LazyOne perhaps, but not sure how useful it would be. we literally had a custom script that checked the very last parameter of the command, and assumed it was a file path without validating at all.

Comment: In such case there is no need for tickets.

Answer (score 34):

**tl;dr**

I only could resolve this by removing the system installed phpunit instance from my system (Linux):

```
sudo apt remove phpunit-*
```

**Details**

Even if the setting in PhpStorm was to use composer autoloader:
[image: phpunit library should use composer]

for some reason it ended up using TeamCity from `/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/Log/TeamCity.php`:
[image]

Project's local PHPUnit was 6.2 while the system default was 5.1 -> they're incompatible.

Comment: I use Laravel and I had to remove the Phpunit installed by the operating system, thanks.

Comment: This solved my issue here. Just to complement, you can also install latest phpunit globally using composer after removing the system installed composer. `composer g require phpunit/phpunit`

Answer (score 24):

I spent half a day struggling with this. The underlying issue is switching between PHPUnit versions (`6.x.x` -> `4.x.x`). (Happened to me by switching branches)

A click on the refresh button in the PHPUnit preferences fixes it.

(`Languages & Frameworks > PHP > PHPUnit`)

Make sure the version of PHPUnit it thinks you have matches the one it reports.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I've filed a ticket here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36632

Comment: I encountered this going from PHPUnit `5.x` -> `4.x`. The location in PHPStorm has changed to `Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Test Frameworks`

Comment: You sir have saved me half a day in working through ancient code. Take my upvote.

Answer (score 3):

This `--teamcity` option is used by PHPStorm to output tests result.

What you're facing is an issue caused by PHP7 and an old version of PHPUnit.

Remove your PHPUnit 5 and install the latest one (currently 6.2) with composer and use PHPUnit namespaces instead.

More info on this bug: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2460

Comment: The normal thing would always be to go for the latest version of things, but sometimes (i.e. in my case at work) we have to use older versions of PHP/PHPUnit because there's  software running on those versions already and upgrading those actually breaks them. You cannot go always for the latest :/